# Display a title of a definition list?

Tags: html

I have some definition lists which group pictures with definitions of those pictures.  What element can I use inside the `dl` to display a title for the list?  For example, to display "Calicos" or "Tabbys" with the lists below:

```
<dl id="calicos">
  <dt>Abby</dt>
  <dd><img src="http://placekitten.com/200/200?image=8" /></dd>
  <dt>Beverly</dt>
  <dd><img src="http://placekitten.com/200/200?image=7" /></dd>
</dl>

<dl id="tabbys">
  <dt>Carlos</dt>
  <dd><img src="http://placekitten.com/200/200?image=16" /></dd>
  <dt>Davy</dt>
  <dd><img src="http://placekitten.com/200/200?image=13" /></dd>
</dl>
```

Ideally, I'd like to do this without JavaScript.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

None. You can't put anything other than a `<dt>` or `<dd>` under a `<dl>`.

Consider something like this instead:

```
<section id="calicos">
  <h2>Calicos</h2>

  <dl>
    <dt>Abby</dt>
    <dd><img src="http://placekitten.com/200/200?image=8" /></dd>
    <dt>Beverly</dt>
    <dd><img src="http://placekitten.com/200/200?image=7" /></dd>
  </dl>
</section>

<section id="tabbys">
  <h2>Tabbys</h2>

  <dl>
    <dt>Carlos</dt>
    <dd><img src="http://placekitten.com/200/200?image=16" /></dd>
    <dt>Davy</dt>
    <dd><img src="http://placekitten.com/200/200?image=13" /></dd>
  </dl>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

The appropriate markup is an `h2` or other heading element before the `dl` element.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

```
<details>
  <summary>Calicos</summary>
  <dl id="calicos">
      <dt>Abby</dt>
      <dd><img src="http://placekitten.com/200/200?image=8" /></dd>
      <dt>Beverly</dt>
      <dd><img src="http://placekitten.com/200/200?image=7" /></dd>
  </dl>
</details>
<details>
  <summary>Tabbys</summary>
  <dl id="tabbys">
    <dt>Carlos</dt>
    <dd><img src="http://placekitten.com/200/200?image=16" /></dd>
    <dt>Davy</dt>
    <dd><img src="http://placekitten.com/200/200?image=13" /></dd>
  </dl>
</details>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DCnYC/1/
​

Comment: Even though `<details>` and `<summary>` are new HTML5 items, you still cannot put anything other than a `<dt>` or `<dd>` in a `<dl>`

Comment: @idrumgood Didn't know that. Adjusted accordingly. Thanks.  Good correction. ;)